# duplicate logging configuration defined while working on iis8 mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, web-config, iis-8

[image]

I am trying to run the application in IIS. when I run it in IIS Express it works fine but when I run it in IIS only the error as shown in the picture occurs, please zoom in the browser for clear picture in error. I am unable to find what is going wrong. So please help.

here is my web.config

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="extnet" type="Ext.Net.GlobalConfig" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
      <section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

Its running fine in IISExpress.

This is the result in command when I run this command 
findstr /p /s /i /c:loggingConfiguration c:*.config 
as kev said
[image]

Comment: Could you include top of your web.config file?

Answer (score 0):

As always with IIS, the clue is in the error message:

> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

This tells us there's something broken with the `web.config` file.

> **Config Error** There is a duplicate 'loggingConfiguration' section defined

IIS is telling us it found duplicate configuration sections

> `9: <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, ... />`

...and here's the offending section an line 9 of your `web.config` file.

Check your `web.config` file to see if two of those sections exist. If you deployed your app into a subdirectory then your parent `web.config` probably has this defined already (`web.config` settings are inherited).

In addition to checking the above, also take a peek in:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
```

There may be a logging config section defined in one of those files.

Comment: it is running fine in IIS Express

Comment: @SanjayMaharjan - That may be so, but have you checked your `web.config` file for duplicate config sections?

Comment: @SanjayMaharjan - also check the parent directory, there could be a `web.config` file in there that your site is inheriting from.

Comment: It is parent web config and as far as I see there is no duplicate logging config any where.

Comment: The same project runs in othere computers perfectly

Comment: @SanjayMaharjan - did you check the other locations I added to my answer?

Comment: yes I checked in machine.config and web.confin inside .net framework there was no duplicate logging config. I also tried after resetting it but still same problem is shown

Comment: @SanjayMaharjan - did you install this using NuGet?

Comment: nope. It is added in another package. It is working on other computers  but not working on this one.

Comment: @SanjayMaharjan - what happens if you remove that line on your IIS8 server? Are IIS Express and IIS8 on the same computer or different computers?

Comment: if I remove the line the error is shown in the line below it. IIS Express and IIS8 are on same server

Comment: @SanjayMaharjan - ok run this from an administrator command line: `findstr /p /s /i /c:loggingConfiguration c:\*.config` and post the results into your question.

Comment: Morning @SanjayMaharjan - thanks for that, an image is hard for me to work with. Can you re-run and pipe the output to a file e.g.`findstr /p /s /i /c:loggingConfiguration c:\*.config > results.txt` then paste the contents of `results.txt` instead.